# Correct output of running Go benchmarks

Tags: performance, go, testing, benchmarking

When I am running a benchmark on this [repository](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd) (just a placeholder for any go project) using:

```
 go test -run="^$" -bench="^BenchmarkLessorRevoke1000$"  ./...
```

The output I am getting is [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/geekodour/12ce7357216b298475bc358303733eeb/raw/150c152e8fd8858e2a6e222f11d1bc42f1be88c4/gistfile1.txt), the benchmark results are shown:

```
BenchmarkLessorRevoke1000-8      1033351          1141 ns/op
```

but also with a whole bunch of other test output. how do I make it only show the benchmarks and not the test outputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can supply a dummy name to the `-run` parameter of the `go test` tool and providing you don't have any tests matching that name, then only the benchmarks should get ran.

You covered this with `"^$"` so all good, you are also have a pattern to match a benchmarks with `"^BenchmarkLessorRevoke1000$"`.

The issue is that you are running go test throughout the entire package and/or subdirectories with the `./...`.

You should specify the benchmarks that you want to run on a per package basis.

```
go test -run="$^" -bench="^BenchmarkLessorRevoke1000$" .
go test -run="$^" -bench="^BenchmarkLessorRevoke1000$" ./pkg1/
go test -run="$^" -bench="^BenchmarkLessorRevoke1000$" ./pkg2/
```

[Also be mindful, if you do want to run benchmarks in mass you should do so on a per-package basis.](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23729#issuecomment-363951207)

> Running benchmarks for multiple packages will execute them concurrently, skewing your results.

Comment: It's puts out the same output as the question I posted. :(

Comment: @Hrishikesh I have update the answer with a bit more of an explanation of what is going on. Hope that helps.